# MediaRecorder Error: setAudioSource in invalid state(4)

Tags: android, runtimeexception, mediarecorder, android-mediarecorder

I've been trying to get a custom camera screen to work, but for some reason the following code does not seem to work. I end up with a `RuntimeException`, caused by an error that says: `setAudioSource called in an invalid state(4)`.

The following is the code in question:

```
 Preview.getRecorderInstance().setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
 Preview.getRecorderInstance().setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
 Preview.getRecorderInstance().setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
 Preview.getRecorderInstance().setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
 Preview.getRecorderInstance().setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.MPEG_4_SP);

 Preview.getRecorderInstance().setOutputFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
                            + "/test" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".mp4"
                    );


 Preview.getRecorderInstance().prepare();
 Preview.getRecorderInstance().start();
```

`Preview.getRecorderInstance()` gets the singleton media recorder tied to the `Preview` class (which is a subclass of `SurfaceView` designed to display the camera preview).

My permissions:
    `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>`

I'd appreciate any help with this, as I'm not getting anywhere in this endeavor, and I've looked at similar questions on stackoverflow. I wasn't able to fix the problem after reading the responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The required ordering of the statements to configure the `MediaRecorder` is tricky.  The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html#setAudioSource(int)) states that `setAudioSource()` must be called before `setOutputFormat()`.  Flip the order of the statements to be like this:

```
 Preview.getRecorderInstance().setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
 Preview.getRecorderInstance().setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! That gets rid of that error, but on the other hand now I get an error saying `start failed: -19`. The problem is when i go to start the recorder, and I'm not able to figure out why.

Comment: @adilipan: Other SO posts suggest this error may be related to the size of the video as set by `MediaRecorder.setVideoSize()`.  Are you calling that method in your code?

Comment: No, I'm not calling that method at all in my code at all.

Answer (score 2):

Just follow MediaRecord document offcial. Your code maybe is not follow the instruction. The order of functions call must be right.

```
        mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
    mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(_path);
```